# Uiimagepicker For showing camera

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi everyone I am trying to make a camera app. I am doing this as

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

where picker is the object of UIimagepicker Controller.

But when is run the code then the application terminates showing the error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'

I am using this on simulator. I know that it is not possible to check camera in simulator, but we can test for that. I think it might be that because camera is not available thats why it's terminating.
But I saw an application with the same code but that was running on the simulator, just showing the camera view.
Just help me out how to resolve this problem. And moreover how can I put my custom view to the camera in that app?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to check if the device has camera available before setting the sourcetype.

The following can check if device has camera available.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
}
```

You can't check the camera functionality from your simulator. You can assign `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` as the sourceType to test on simulator.

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya I have done that,but i was wondering that how that application was showing camera view on the simulator,but not was able to click as hardware was needed.

Comment: the Operating System requires a driver to operate the external device. iOS doesn't have the driver for the MacBook's camera.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.2**

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
  presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
  print("The device has no camera")
}
```

Saved photos album

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) {
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
  self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Below Code Where Exception Occures. Remember You Need To Implement navigationController

```
 if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            UIAlertController *alertView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"No Camera Avalible" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:alertView completion:nil];
        }];
        [alertView addAction:ok];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```